# hyper link in the reference

Tags: bibtex, hyperref

I can generate a cite link from text to reference, and I also like to make the content in the reference become a hyper link as well, here is my code, refered from [sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex):

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
     colorlinks   = true,
     linkcolor    = blue,
     citecolor    = red
}

\begin{document}
Ths document is an example of BibTeX using in bibliography management. Three items 
are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, the Einstein
journal paper \cite{einstein}, and the Donald Knuth's website \cite{knuthwebsite}. 
The \LaTeX\ related items are \cite{latexcompanion,knuthwebsite}. 

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{test_bib}
\end{document}
```

in the test_bib.bib, I write like:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "\href{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.htm}{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

hyper link in content has no problem:
[image]

but in reference itself, no hyper link (I should be blue in 3rd one I think):
[image]

What is my code problem? how to achieve this?

Comment: I guess that you are looking for the `backref=page` option of the `hyperref` package.

Comment: @Fran i need in the reference page, link the document to a web site, which can directly open the referenced doc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way to achcieve that, original code for *.bib:

```
@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "\href{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.htm}{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

change to

```
@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "\href{http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.htm}{Knuth: Computers and Typesetting}",
    url       = {http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html}
}
```

[image]

Then I can click the link the reference and go to the website directly.

Comment: It does not work for me! I want to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62870417/how-to-incorporate-reference-links-into-reference-names-in-a-bibliography-to-mak

Comment: Would've been useful to highlight that the only difference is the "" changed to {}. Took me a while to spot it lol. And it does not work for me by the way..